# Filter datefield in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to filter datefield in Django as:

- start range lookup to find items created plus 1 hour
- end range now

Range is quite simple. Just need grab book entries that have created, plus 1 hour to now.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), 
    default=timezone.now)
```

There is end now filter. how to add 1 hour plus on start.\

```
Book.objects.filter(created__lte=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
```

Every book has a different created datetime. I want add 1 hour to created. Then filter .

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking for. Are you trying to get books created in the past hour?

Comment: What do you mean by `start range lookup to find items created plus 1 hour `?

Comment: Every book as created datetime. I want add 1 hour to created. Then filter them.

Comment: @bobsr, but each book has different created datetime.

Comment: @pythad created is different for all of them

Comment: @bobsr, Yes, so if created is different for all of them, where do we need to add 1 hour?

Comment: @bobsr why you need to add 1 hour. If you explain that maybe we will undestand and help you

Comment: @pythad created is different for all. that i am asking it here, maybe there is has to be a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not very clear what you are asking but here is how you can add 1 hours to the current datetime :
`datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)`

Here is an example, if you search books created during the last hour :

```python
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import now

start_date = now()
end_date = start_date - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
Book.objects.filter(created__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Check [datetime - Basic date and time types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) documentation for more information

Comment: Every book as a different created datetime. I want add 1 hour to created. Then filter them.

Comment: then is this what you want? : `Book.objects.filter(created__lte=(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)))`

Comment: What I don't understand is that you are searching Book in the future, Books which are not added because you add one hour to the current date. What do you want exactly? Is it not the reverse? get all books added during the last hour?

Comment: you are close, this is one hour to current time, Instead i would like to add hour to created

Comment: It doesn't make sens, you will have no results. Think about it... you are still searching books that are not added if you add one hour to each book creation date. Tell me with a sentence what do you want to get. E.g : all books that have been created 3 days ago. But you can't ask, "I want all books that are created 1 hours after their creation."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95630/discussion-between-louis-barranqueiro-and-bobsr).